# Unable to run "adb", check your Android SDK installation and ANDROID SDK_ROOT environment variable:

Tags: flutter, adb

Unable to run "adb", check your Android SDK installation and ANDROID SDK_ROOT environment variable: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

i have set up everything related to flutter, but no adb devices& flutter devices & my physical phone also not showing in Android studio.

i have also set path and environment variable as said in the error.
If you have any way of solving this problem, please let me know.

Comment: can you try  ```adb uninstall < package_name>```      eg: adb uninstall com.android.myapp

Answer (score 0):

your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT variable should be :

environment variable: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

and not

environment variable: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

1. In Windows Bar type in Search: "Environment properties"
   This should open System Properties
2. Select "Enrvironment Variables"
3. Select "Path" Variable and click "Edit"
4. Seperate the Path's witch semicolon ";"
   e.g. C:\flutter\bin; C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk; etc.
5. Restart your computer or Logout from Account and login.

Try to start adb again

Comment: yes.it worked.Also my system had other adb folders, that i used to unlock my bootloader of my phone. It was causing some kind of conflict between the sdk and platform tools. I removed evey adb files and folders except that of the installed sdk and it worked. Thank you for your responses and your time. :D